# custom MXML container in Flex 4

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I want to make a custom container, usable in MXML like:

```
<local:MyContainer>
  <s:Label/>
  <s:Button/>
  ...
</local:MyContainer>
```

...but I'd like to be able to catch when the children are added so that I can control stuff like when & where they're added.

I tried overriding addChild(), addChildAt(), addElement(), addElementAt(), (extending the Group class) but they only fire when you add elements specifically with those functions - the application launches and the label, button, etc, end up in MyContainer without calling these functions.

How do I control the addition of sub-components via MXML?  Am I on the wrong track - should I be writing a custom layout and/or skin instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to overwrite the setter of the [mxmlContent-Array](http://help.adobe.com/de_DE/AS3LCR/Flex_4.0/spark/components/Group.html?allClasses=1#mxmlContent). Probably this is used instead of addChild()...

Comment: Thanks for your answer - you're right, it calls that.  Looking at the source code for Group, it appears that the Group internally uses the private function elementAdded() to do the real leg-work of adding an element.  In other words, the SDK cheats to avoid calling addElement for MXML elements.

However, the comment "This method is used internally by Flex and is not intended for direct use by developers." in front of the method makes me uneasy about trying to use it.  Must learn more about custom layouts...

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that this works and it might be helpful for you. It has a downside. The Designer will display an error message "Multiple sets of visual children have been specified for the  tag".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import avmplus.getQualifiedClassName;

            import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;

            import mx.core.IVisualElement;
            import mx.core.UIComponent;

            import spark.layouts.BasicLayout;
            import spark.layouts.VerticalLayout;

            private var customMxmlContent : Array = null;
            private var customInitializeDone : Boolean = false;
            override public function set mxmlContent(value:Array) : void {

                if(!customInitializeDone) {
                    // customInitializeDone == false:
                    // this is called when the elements that are defined in THIS
                    // mxml file are added to mxmlContent. 
                    super.mxmlContent = value;
                    customInitializeDone = true;

                } else { 
                    // customInitializeDone:
                    // called when the elements from another mxmls file are added.
                    // Another file uses this component in this way:
                    /*
                    <views:RoundedGroup width="100%">
                        <views:layout>
                            <s:VerticalLayout/>
                        </views:layout>

                        <s:Button label="1234" />
                        <s:Button label="5678" />
                    </views:RoundedGroup>
                     */
                    // Here it is redirected to the innerGroup
                    // if you do not do this, the content of THIS mxml file is
                    // replaced by the other content
                    for(var i:uint=0; i < value.length; i++) {
                        innerGroup.addElement(value[i] as IVisualElement);
                    }
                }

                // Reset the layout 
                if(this.layout != null) {
                    // find out the layout class that is applied to this
                    var layClass : Class =  getDefinitionByName(getQualifiedClassName(this.layout)) as Class;
                    // and apply it to innerGroup instead
                    innerGroup.layout = new layClass();
                    // and reset the layout of this to a BasicLayout to get the Rect to the correct
                    // position and the innerGroup above the Rect
                    this.layout = new BasicLayout();
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

        <s:Rect left="10" right="10" top="10" height="100%"  radiusX="11" radiusY="11">
            <s:fill>
                <s:SolidColor color="0xB7C8A8" />
            </s:fill>
            <s:stroke>
                <s:SolidColorStroke color="0xABABAB" weight="1" />
            </s:stroke>
        </s:Rect>

        <!-- Items are added within set mxmlContent to this VGroup container -->
        <s:Group id="innerGroup" left="10" right="10" top="10" />
</s:Group>
```